# Foundation and modals/reveal

Tags: html, css, forms, zurb-foundation

I'm running into issues with modals and forms with Foundation.

I want to be able to fill out a form, open a modal, then have that modal be able to submit the form.

Normally, I'd have my form, and all of it's form fields, and put the modal inside the the form element, and that would be fine - but with foundation, I find that the reveal modal is moved to the bottom of the DOM.

What's the best way to accomplish what I'm after?

I've added a skeleton of what my normal structure might be like - any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

```
<form method="post" action="...">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Enter campaign title here" required>

     <label for="title">Description</label>
     <textarea type="text" name="description" placeholder="Description of this campaign"></textarea>

     <button type="button" class="button default-btn float-right" data-open="emailSendConfirmation">Publish campaign</button>

    <div class="reveal" id="emailSendConfirmation" data-reveal>         
        <button data-close aria-label="Close modal" type="button" class="button">Cancel</button>
        <button type="submit" class="button" name="status" value="Published">Publish</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Thanks, 
Ollie